# Make program unkillable or auto-restarting for non-admin users

Tags: windows, process, user-permissions

I installed [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/) on my PC, and I created a non-admin account where I intend to do most of my work. (The admin account has a very long password which I printed out on a piece of paper, hopefully adding enough friction for me to not use it unless I positively need to.)

What I would like to achieve is:

- RescueTime to auto-start (done; used `shell:common startup`)
- Either:

  - RescueTime to either be unkillable in Task Manager (I figured, if it runs as the admin user, or a service, a non-priv user cannot kill it—right? Can I write some sort of "service file" like in systemd that achieves this?)
  - RescueTime to auto-restart like a second after it's been killed.

I'm a linux engineer, but I don't know anything about Windows or GUI applications.
Please help. My brain refuses to foster any kind of self-discipline, so I must resort to this kind of nonsense!

(Any other approaches / suggestions are also welcome—different software, etc.)

Comment: Can you try this? As long as the process runs with high privileges, a regular user shouldn't be able to kill it. https://superuser.com/questions/418136/how-to-run-an-exe-on-boot-and-keep-it-running-regardless-of-who-logs-in-on-wind